# PHP, getting Undefined property: stdClass::$id but it definitely exists

Tags: php, object

So it's really simple code and I am yanking my hair out with the problem.

```
//I first retrieve some JSON info (confirmed to work fine)
$file=file_get_contents('url');
//I then decode and print to verify (still working)
$somename=json_decode($file);
```

I print it out just to make sure it works (it does):

```
print_r($somename);
```

The print out reads as follows:

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 456456456 [name] => somename [Stuff01] => 55 [Stuff02] => 25 [Stuff03] => 123132123132 ) )
```

Now I just want to get the value in the 'id' key so I use the appropriate object call:

```
$thisID=$somename->{'id'};
```

But I get the error:

> **Notice**: Undefined property: `stdClass::$id`

I print_r every time so I know it's there. I can see it. What am I doing wrong?

I have had no problems doing this exact thing many times.

Comment: Try var_dump($somename->id); too see what it gives  you...

Comment: I got the following:: object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["somename"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (5) { ["id"]=> int(456456456 ) ["name"]=> string(5) "somename" ["Stuff01"]=> int(55) ["Stuff02"]=> int(25) ["Stuff03"]=> int(123132123132 ) } }

Comment: When using var_dump with the key id specified I get NULL and the same undefined error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How do you access to individual properties is based on your data structure. You have kind of nested structure, object in object. Try like this:

```
 $somename->somename->id;
 //or    
 $yourObjectName->somename->id;
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yea, I got it. thanks a lot for the var_dump answer, that will come in usefull later i'm sure. here's what happened I think: When i print_r the object it was not showing the 'somename' as a key value before the other info. as you can see by what I printed. The reason (ithink) is because I missed a closing '>' in one of my echo '<br'; before it, like so. It shows it now, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad if it helped. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted...And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I can't upvote you yet it seems but I will mark it as accepted as soon as I see how. BAM. Accepted! thanks again